# Mouse over stringgrid when dragging?

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

Parts of my stringgrid are eligible drop targets, and some are not (first row is column headings, first column is a sort of index and subsequent columns may be dropped to). I have that coded and working.

Now I am thinking that it might be nice to gve a visual indiation to the user as he drags the mouse over a cell which is a potential drop target. I woudl like to highlight the first cell in the row and column of the cell over which he is currently hovering (or possibly the entire row and column, forming a sort of crosshair; I am as yet undecided). I reckon I can code that in `OnDrawCell`.

I had thought to use `OnMouseMove` and cehck `if Dragging then`, but ...

My problem is that when I am dragging the `OnMouseMove` event never gets called.

Is there any other way to know when the cursor is hovering over a strigngrid during a drag operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`OnDragOver event`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnDragOver) is specifically designed for doing this; it's called automatically, and provides the `X` and `Y` coordinates where the mouse pointer is located. There's a code sample available at that link location that demonstrates using it as well - it's for a `TListBox`, but the principle is the same.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Add('Not');
  ListBox1.Items.Add('In');
  ListBox1.Items.Add('Alphabetical');
  ListBox1.Items.Add('Order');
end;

// This OnDragOver event handler allows the list box to
// accept a dropped label.

procedure TForm1.ListBox1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
  State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := Source is TLabel;
end;
```

Comment: +1 and the answer, @kenWhite ... and  may I take this opportunity to say "D'oh!"?  Sorry, I was coding until dark o'clock and rose before dawn to continue. This shows that I shoudl probably stop coding until I wake up ;-)  Thanks, as always, for your help.

Comment: What if the drag originates from another application? DragOver and MouseMove) is never called!

Comment: @Mike: That would be a totally separate question (and answer); for cross-application drag and drop you have to use OLE drag functionality, which involves different methods and registration with the shell as a dragdrop client.

Comment: Actually it took multiple readings before I figured out this was intra-app, so although I agree it is a different process, the formulation of the question remains the same. I know how to d&d between apps, but not the answer to the question of this topic for that scenario. If you do, I'd be happy to make a post with the same topic.